# Divide a div element

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a way to cut a div into number of pieces using **JavaScript** or **CSS**. I have a long div with contents inside it. I need to split the div according to a certain height and show each division as a separate block. What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Suppose the height of the main div is 1500px. I need to split the div into 3 pieces each with a height of 500px.

If the height of the div is 1600px, it should be split into 4 pieces. First 3 with a height of 500px each and the last with a height of 100px.

Comment: Please post the code for the div in question, and link to the page where we can see it.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly weird, your question.

What determines the original height of the div, if it isn't your code? The size of the contents?

You *could* dynamically poll the size of your div using javascript, then create extra divs and append them behind, then (I presume) split up your content across the divs (by some hacky rule of thumb), but if you're going to go to that kind of lengths, why not do it in advance on the server? Especially as on the client you'd have to wait for the browser to finish rendering the first time to be able to calculate the height (I imagine), so there would probably be some highly unaesthetical effects.

Comment: I need the browser to finish rendering my content, because after loading the content only I can calculate the number of divs into which my content spans.

Comment: And what if your content contains images, can they always be cut into 'div-sized' chunks? And what happens in different browsers? And what happens when a user 'zooms in' on the page?

Comment: Anything that is shown in the main div will be cut into separate pieces.

Answer (score 0):

A div cannot be cut into separate pieces.  It can be styled to have certain height and width.

Comment: How can I apply the style? I have done using the clip property. Is there any other alternative?

Comment: you can use style="height:200px; width:200px; overflow:hidden;"

Comment: But I have to show the remaining text in the second div and so on.

Answer (score -1):

You can set something up to poll the height of the element and then add or remove 500px div's from the containing div.

Here's an example of how to get the height of the div that will continue checking every 5 seconds:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkDiv() {
        alert(document.getElementById('FormBody').offsetHeight);
        setTimeout(checkDiv, 5000);
    }
    setTimeout(checkDiv, 5000);
</script>
```

The next step is to call appendChild on 'FormBody' to add in a new div using the DOM.